# How do you prevent input type="date" from shifting around in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, datepicker

I have a  Pen https://codepen.io/trajano/pen/wvgWKyd with the following code that will show a text field that when I click on it will set the type to `date`.

```
<div class="x">
  <input id="i" 
         type="text"
         placeholder="which does not appear on date input"
         onfocus="f()" 
         onblur="b()"/>
</div>
```

```
.x {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 50px;
  input {
    min-width: 200px;
    max-width: 200px;
    min-height: 20px;
  }
}
```

```
const f = () => {
  (document.getElementById("i") as HTMLInputElement).type="date";
  (document.getElementById("i") as HTMLInputElement).focus();
};

const b = () => {
   (document.getElementById("i") as HTMLInputElement).type="text";
 
};
```

The problem is on Chrome it changes the size of the control.  It is okay on Firefox.  I set the background to red and large so the change is more obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Simple.

Set the height of the input to 20px (or the height you need) and add box-sizing: border-box;